# Authenticate Users based on AD group membership. Ubuntu 14.04 , Cant find help anywhere

Tags: active-directory, ssh, ubuntu-14.04

Been Googling for two days now. I am not new to Linux, but am new to AD and using it in Linux.

So. I have an AD system ( not run be me ) and its joined happily. I followed this procedure: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html

Now, I can SSH in using ANY AD user account.

I would like to restrict users from SSHing / Logging into the console / system based one their group membership. Say a group called. "Linux Users"

If they are not in this group, then deny access. Otherwise allow SSH / Login. Local Linux users should also be allowed in as normal.

Any ideas?
I cant find anything. Or at least, I cant find anything that relates to how ive set it up based on the Ubuntu tutorial.

Thanks in advance guys.
-G

Comment: Your question's title is very misleading. Maybe you should put in that you are trying to restrict SSH users?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSSD you should be able to add a DenyGroups (or AllowGroups) in your sshd_config. See man sshd_config for more but it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: If you use SSSD make sure the group you are authenticating against in AD is a security group and not a normal distribution group. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc781446(v=ws.10).aspx